# Why file is required however variable is still undefined

Tags: php, require-once

I try to understand OOP ways in PHP. And I think -not sure for this case- I have issues with variable scopes. Here are **my questions**:

1. After running `test.php`; why I can't access `$nums` variable in
   `foo.php`?
2. What is the solution?
3. If the solution requires to use `global` keyword somewhere, what is
   my other option without `global` keyword. (I don't want to use it)

**foo.php**

```
<?php
$nums = array(4, 7);
$s = $nums[0]+$nums[1];
echo 'string in foo.php is written here.<br> SUM is '.$s.'<br>';
print_r($nums);
echo '<br><br>';
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

class Loader {

    private static $load_name;

    public static function loadFile($load_file) {

        self::$load_name = $load_file;

        $file_to_load = self::$load_name;

        require_once($file_to_load);

        unset($file_to_load);
    }
}

class TestClass {

    public function getnums() 
    {
        $a = Loader::loadFile("foo.php");

        echo 'var_dump($a) :<br><pre>'; var_dump($a); echo '</pre>'; 

        echo 'var_dump($nums) :<br><pre>'; var_dump($nums);     echo '</pre>';
    }
}

$n = new TestClass();
$g = $n->getnums();

echo 'var_dump($g) :<br><pre>'; var_dump($g); echo '</pre>';
```

**test.php returns**

```
string in foo.php is written here.
SUM is 11
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 7 ) 

var_dump($a) :
NULL

var_dump($nums) :


Notice:  Undefined variable: nums in ...UniServerZ\www\test.php on line 27

NULL

var_dump($g) :
NULL
```

Comment: [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).... you're doing the include inside a class method, so the scope of variables defined in that file is that class method.... if necessary, get the method to return a list/array of all variables defines inside its scope using something like [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're 100% correct - the issue is with the scopes.

`$nums` will only be defined in the scope of the file and the including scope; in this instances thats the `Loader::loadFile()` function.

If you want to retrieve the variable out of the file and make it available in your `getnums()` method, you'll need a way for it to be returned from loadFile.  I believe you're assuming this happens automatically with the variable `$a`.

To make this work, try:

```
public static function loadFile($filename) {
  // ... existing code
  return $nums;
}
```

And then $a will be $nums.

To make this more verbose and reusable:

```
function loadFile($filename, $variableName) {
  // existing code here.
  return $$variableName; // variable variables are a dangerous thing to debug.
}
```

Therefore your getnums() function will look like:

```
$a = Loader::loadFile("foo.php", "nums"); // "nums" being the variable name.
```

Comment: Side note, using variable variables may lead to E_NOTICES being thrown where you make a typo in the string, resulting in the variable not being defined when its attempting to return $$name